# iOS, how to support multiple languages properly

Tags: ios

We currently have an English app on the AppStore and have decided to support another language. But I'm not sure where to start.

How should the app content be created to be able to support this? Should I just create two separate applications in their respective language and submit them both to the AppStore? Or do I have to create one app with some kind of mechanism that translates on the fly??

I somehow don't think that flooding the AppStore with multiple versions of my app would be the way to go (at least in the eyes of the Apple Review team).

Any ideas?

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-localization-with-nslocalizedstring/ is a starting example on how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks good but how would this apply to, let's say, the app description?

Comment: From iTunes connect you can manages the language for the description, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to use the localization of iOS. You should not upload different apps!

See this link for a tutorial: [How to localize an iPhone app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial)